# mvc4 app, hide iis application name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I have a mvc4 application deployed to IIS7.5.

The Website is mapletest, the application is Budget2013,
so users access the site, mapletest/Budget2013.

What do i need to do to allow users to access this by just using mapletest?

Also, mapletest/Budget2013/ShoppingCenter should become mapletest/ShoppingCenter.

Basically I want to hide the application name in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You should deploy directly your application to the root website and not using a virtual directory. So for example if your `mapletest` WebSite physical directory is `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mapletest` that's where you should deploy your application.

Comment: I have done this but I can't get it to iis to serve any content unless there is an application running under the website is iis.

Comment: When you create a new website, it automatically creates an application. You don't need to be creating sub applications for this to work.

Comment: I think I am having issues with port 80 being used by Default Web Site also.

Comment: Yes of course. If you want to have 2 websites listening on the same port (80 in your case) you will have to bind them to different DNS records.